# "Too many connections" error when inserting in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, cron

I'm having a hard time understanding what's going wrong here. I have a Wordpress site with many plugins. One of them uses Wordpress' native cron-like functionality, `wp-cron`, to insert many posts which are obtained via a webservice. The posts are inserted using Wordpress' native functions like `insert_post` in a foreach loop. After a while, the maximum number of connections is reached (currently set at 300), and I get the "too many connections error" and my whole site becomes unreachable. It clears up by itself after a while.
Here's what I don't understand: the posts are inserted in a normal foreach loop, so synchronously, and the traffic on the site is low as well, so how can it run out of connections?
I can clearly see the connections being used up in the PHPMyAdmin monitor. I've read online about having these problems when using persistent connections, but as far as I can tell those are not being used. (Again, it's just using native Wordpress functions for inserting.)
Any idea what I'm missing?

[image: Oh no…][image: Aack! Hmmm…]

Comment: I would suggest you post some code otherwise people can only guess

Comment: I agree with the previous commenter: we need code. I am not really familiar with wordpress internals, but it seems that your connections are not closed over time and each insert is ran through a new connection.

Comment: It's not a simple code fragment. The code wasn't written by me; it's in one of the plugins and obfuscated by obscurity.

Comment: It seems that everytime the insertion code runs the connection is opened and thus you get too many connection error, Try and find to close the connection immediately after the insertion is complete. This will help reduce the connection count. Thus the error would go away